# Linq XML Dynamic building

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am building an xml file.   Parts of the file are static.   Some of the file is dynamic.   My code has an error of  “Null object reference”.

Any tips would be awesome.

```
private XElement BuildDataElement()
{
    // this is going to be more complicated
    return new XElement("data");
}

public void TestXML(string fname)
{
    // build the data element
    XElement allData = BuildDataElement();

    // Build the header
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("map",
            new XAttribute("showLabels", "1"),
            new XAttribute("includeNameInLabels", "1"),
            new XElement("colorRange",
                new XElement("color",
                new XAttribute("minValue", "1")
                )
            ),
            allData,
            new XElement("application",
                new XElement("apply",
                    new XAttribute("toObject", "TOOLTIP"),
                    new XAttribute("styles", "TTipFont,MyDataPlotStyle")
                )
            )
         )
     );

    if (File.Exists(fname))
        File.Delete(fname);
    doc.Save(fname);
         }
```

Comment: I can't see why you'd get a NullReferenceException in that code. Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The code as you provided it ran just fine for me in LINQPad.  Perhaps you're passing a null filename into TestXML?

Answer (score 7):

> Any tips would be awesome.

You got it. Here are my tips:

- Obtain a debugger.
- Set the debugger to break at all exceptions.
- Run your code in the debugger until the null reference exception happens.
- Figure out which value was null that you did not expect to be null.
- Either insert a check for null that handles the situation where the value is null correctly, or change the logic so that it becomes impossible for that value to be null.
- Thoroughly code-review and test the fix.
- Write a regression test for your test suites that verifies that this bug doesn't come back.

Comment: Agreed, figure out the line the error is on with a debugger first instead of posting the whole method.

Answer (score 0):

The only way in the snippet provided I can see getting an error would be 2 two places.

```
BuildDataElement();
```

Could be generating the error, rather than the Xml document.

Next if `BuildDataElement();` returns that might be the problem, since I am guessing the XDocument is doing a `.ToString()` or some action on `allData`